# Implementing Apple Push Notification Service through Java

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

```
//Try to connect to APNs     
pushManager.initializeConnection(HOST,PORT,"/etc/Certificates.p12", "password",      SSLConnectionHelper.KEYSTORE_TYPE_PKCS12);
```

Which password am I referencing here? Is it my appleid password?

Answer (score 1):

It's the private key of the .p12 file. The password is required when you export (save) the .p12 file.